# UiImageView with animation goes too big

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have A class inheriting from `UIImageView`. Then I have the `NSArray` containing the the object of the A class containing some pictures. Then I just want to add to the Main view (`self.view addSubview: "object of Aclass"`) and remove some of them. I would keep doing that for a certain amount of time. Here is question. When i do "add" and "remove" the `UIImageView` (A class object) with some `Animation` like when I add, the `UIImageView` goes from small to its original size and when i remove, it goes from its original size to smaller

```
-(void)displayAClassObject: {
[self.view addSubview: AClassObject];
AClassObject.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3, 0.3);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{ AClassObject.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; } completion:^(BOOL finished) {  }];
}
```

Then some function will generate random Number to remove the `AClassObject` added in the Main view.

```
-(void)displayOffAClassObject {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{AClassObject.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);} completion:^(BOOL finished){[AClassObject removeFromSuperview]; }];
[AClassObject removeFromSuperview];
}
```

when i add again the removed `AClassObject` to the main `view`, i set it with different frame to place it in different place in the Main view but i do not change its size.

This process keeps going per a second but when I add only or remove only, It works fine. The `AClassObject` goes from small to its original size and then its original size to small. but when i do both at the same time like `[self displayOffAClassObject]; [self displayAClassObject];`

The `UIImageView` (`AClassObject`) goes really big, even some of the image goes off the screen. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?? or any suggestion to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do transform (especially scale transform), `.frame` become invalid. Set `AClassObject.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity` before setting its frame. If you want to set its position when `.transform` is not identity, set `.center` instead.

Cited from `UIView` documentation:

> WARNING
>
> If this property (.transform) is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform